# ImportExport.Client fails with second request

Tags: core-service, content-porter-2013

When using the `Client.StartExport` command with the Core Service ImportExport client with the BasicHttp binding it works OK the first time, but a second action with the same Client in the Opened state fails.

However, if Fiddler is running on the machine it works fine. I've seen [this article where running fiddler fixes the App](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-) and I'm wondering if I'm having the issue where the HTTPWebRequest is not closed?  I get stuck in the `state != ProcessState.Finished` part. Any ideas?

```
var test = Client.TestConnection();

Debug.WriteLine("Connection: " + test);

Debug.WriteLine("Starting export: " + name);
Directory.CreateDirectory(WorkFolder);
// first export...
var exportInstruction = new ExportInstruction()
{
    LogLevel = LogLevel.Normal,
    BluePrintMode = BluePrintMode.ExportSharedItemsFromOwningPublication,
    ExpandDependenciesOfTypes = IncludeDependencyTypes
};
var selection = new Selection[] { new ItemsSelection(elements) };

_processId = Client.StartExport(selection, exportInstruction);
Debug.WriteLine("Export Process Started: " + _processId);

var state = WaitForProcess();
var result = GetProcessInfo();
if (state != ProcessState.Finished)
{
    throw new Exception("Export process Aborted!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for us, we are using the below after the state is finished.

```
        $importExportServiceClient.Close()
        $importExportServiceClient.Dispose()
        $ImportExportDownloadServiceClient.Close()
        $ImportExportDownloadServiceClient.Dispose()
```